# @font-face Fonts Cropped When Using CSS3 keyframe Animations

Tags: html, css, font-face, css-transitions

I have four absolutely positioned divs that fade in and move using a css3 `@-webkit-keyframe` animation. What I've noticed is that some serifs and descenders of the `@font-face` I'm using get cropped at the automatically calculated edge of the div. (I'm using `text-align: left`, so I only notice this on the left and bottom edges of the div.

I can work around this problem by defining fixed sizes for the divs, and changing to `text-align: center`, but I'm curious if there is a better way to fix this, so I don't have to change the size of the divs if the text changes or if I need to change the `font-size`.

Edit: here is some code to give you an idea of what I'm doing

```
div#text_2
{ 
    position: absolute;
    top: 288px;
    left: 100px;
    font-size: 65px;
    color: #C0DB81;
    font-family: 'TFArrow-Medium'; /* This is defined in another css file */
    -webkit-animation-delay: 0s;
    -webkit-animation-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0, 0, 0.35, 1.0);
    -webkit-transform: translateZ(0);
    -webkit-animation-duration: 4s;
    -webkit-animation-name: text_fade_in2;
}

@-webkit-keyframes text_fade_in2
{
    0%      { opacity: 0; }
    25%     { opacity: 0; }
    50%     { opacity: 1; }
    100%    { opacity: 1; }
}
```

This fixes the cropping issue:

```
div#text_2
{ 
    position: absolute;
    top: 288px;
    left: 100px;
    font-size: 65px;
    color: #C0DB81;
    font-family: 'TFArrow-Medium'; /* This is defined in another css file */
    -webkit-animation-delay: 0s;
    -webkit-animation-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0, 0, 0.35, 1.0);
    -webkit-transform: translateZ(0);
    -webkit-animation-duration: 4s;
    -webkit-animation-name: text_fade_in2;
    height: 65; /* 60px is the auto-calculated height in Safari */
}
```

Comment: Can you replicate this problem in a Fiddle?

Comment: @Mooseman Nope. Can't seem to reproduce it elsewhere...

Comment: Can you provide a link then? There must be other CSS interfering.

Comment: @Mooseman turns out to be a WebKit bug

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I spoke to some WebKit developers, and I found a new WebKit bug. They were speaking in web-rendering terms (of which I am utterly clueless), but I believe this is the issue they opened: https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=117540

A workaround in the meantime is to add this CSS to your webpage (WARNING: this will drastically increase your rendering times for large amounts of text):

```
* { text-rendering: optimizelegibility; }
```